# sql select query is not functioning properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I been trying to fix this sql query. The query is suppose count per day. What I been getting is that it currently will display all days as the total count. Instead of counting Five for Monday, it will count all days at the maximum 10. How can I fix my sql query.

```
 for($setTime = 29; $setTime >= 0; $setTime--){     
 $time = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) 
FROM users 
WHERE time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 29 DAY)) 
GROUP BY DAY(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time))");
```

Basically that query will not display the total for each day but instead it will display 28 days days with a total of 10. How can I fix my MySQL Query??

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_*` for new code this has been deprecated. Instead, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` forms.

Comment: Are you trying to find the unique count for each Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday... etc over the interval? Is that your goal?

Comment: GROUP BY year,month,day

Answer (score 0):

Use `DAYNAME` if you need to get the count for Monday and so on

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id)
FROM users
WHERE time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 29 DAY))
GROUP BY DAYNAME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time))
```

Comment: Actually, if you add dayname(something) to the select clause, it looks like a pretty good answer.